# jdeveloper eclipse shortcuts

Tags: jdeveloper

In Jdeveloper, Loading eclipse keyboard schema is not working. (Eclipse shortcuts Ctrl + O list of methods, Ctrl + Shift + R List of Resources are not working.)

I'm using Jdeveloper 11.1.1.6.0.

How i tried is this.
(Tools > Preference > Shortcuts > (Load Keyboard schema from More Actions DropDown) > Eclipse Schema

Reference : http://web-center-suite.blogspot.in/2011/08/jdeveloper-shortcuts.html

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set those two specifically on your own through tools->properties accelerators.
Look at the Navigate menu in JDeveloper for "Go to file" and for "quick outline" to see the current shortcut.